# System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath()

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mvc, hidden

C#. MVC. Visual Studio 2013. При создании папки для изображений в корне проекта, все создается. Вот только файлы получаются скрытые (в смысле Exclude In Project). В другом проекте такого небыло. В чем может быть причина? Спасибо.

Comment: не могли бы вы привести ваш код? [mcve]

Comment: Вы желаете странного. Сервер не должен ничего знать про проект - потому изменения в файле проекта и не происходят.